# Use fragments with fancy coverflow adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, coverflow, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to implement a cover flow layout using [fancy-coverflow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow). Instead of image I am trying to load fragments. Fancy coverflow supports the use of viewgroup instead of an image. This is the code I am trying to use

```
public View getCoverFlowItem(int i, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

            if (reuseableView != null) {
                linearLayout = (LinearLayout) reuseableView;
            } else
            {


                linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new FancyCoverFlow.LayoutParams(750, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(viewGroup.getContext());
            frame.setId(i+10000);
            linearLayout.addView(frame);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(i+10000,ItemFragment.init(i));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();





            return linearLayout;
        }
```

But this is not working, even if there is only one item to show the getView method is called infinite number of times. But if I remove the fragment transaction commit it will work only once.

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Why do you use setId(i + 1000)?

Comment: I updated code, removed that line. but still no difference.